# Trouble with addeventListener

Tags: javascript, events, dom

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    alert("Got into DOMContentLoaded event");
    document.getElementById("txtSearch").addEventListener("onkeyup", function () {
        //TODO Post to server
        alert("Got into onKeyUp event");
        var data;
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp = XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", "/Home/searchLocs", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        var obj = { "strSearch": document.getElementById("txtSearch").value }
        xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
    });
    alert("Got past search addEventListener");
    alert("onkeyup = " + document.getElementById("txtSearch").onkeyup);
});
```

I'm trying to hook up a javascript eventhandler to

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" style=" width:200px" />
```

Alerts tell me I 
get into the DOMContentLoaded event, 
I get past the addeventListener, 
but onkeyup = null.
IE vs 11+
Is there a problem with my addEventListener syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this replace

```
 addEventListener("onkeyup", function ()
```

with

```
 addEventListener("keyup", function ()
```